# What was Peter Parker’s college major?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, the-amazing-spider-man

In which area did Peter Parker major in at university?

Did he ever show any computer hacking skills or other computer-related interests (computer science)?

Comment: Nobody with an interest in computer science uses Bing.

Comment: LOL... It would be better (not financially, of course) if there was no adds on movies. It interfere on the character understanding. one day we are going to see a "CK" on Super-Man shorts...

Comment: Martha Kent would surely have stitched all of young Clark Kent's underwear with CK, albeit oblivious of any alternative meaning... :)

Comment: ops... pick the wrong example...

Comment: Peter Parker is a natural webmaster.

Comment: I actually use Bing, and I'm majoring in Computer Science and Engineering. On the other hand, I use Bing when I forget to set up google as the main search engine and I'm too lazy to type google.com.

Comment: Arachnology, surely?

Comment: I'll just "bing" it. Said no-one. Ever.

Comment: I'm a computer science major and I use Bing because they bribe me via their rewards program. I've earned about $150 worth of Amazon gift cards by searching (often via a script I wrote to rack up points quickly). So long as they have that rewards program to give me Amazon gift cards, I'll keep using Bing.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the silly song at the end of Into the Spider-verse, he sings that he has a degree in Chemical Engineering. Greatness.

Answer (score 11):

The [Marvel Universe Wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Spider-Man_(Peter_Parker)#ixzz2DI9d03AR) reads:

> Peter Parker graduated high school and earned a science scholarship to Empire State University (ESU) for achieving the highest scholastic average in Midtown High's history.

So while it doesn't say what the major was, it would have had to at least be science based.

ADDON: At some point (in Amazing Spider-Man) adult Peter Parker decides to leave the Bugle and teach high school science. There's a strong hint there.

Comment: And has he ever shown any hacking or computer related interests?

Comment: @TheKrakener Not that I know of, but I'm no expert in the regular universe Spidey. In Ultimate Spider-Man, he gets hired by the Daily Bugle as an all-around computer guy (internal IT and setting up the external web site). He's never left high school in that time line, however. He's also depicted as very curious concerning all fields of science, able to follow white papers written by Tony Stark, for example. But his main field of interest would definitely be chemistry.

Comment: thank you. It is something I've always been curious about, since I see him dealing with different science and engineering areas but never in this particular field...

Comment: In the original Spider-Man comics, I don’t think there was much computer stuff going on — it was the 60s, so computers were a bit more unwieldy in those days.

Answer (score 6):

(Click links to see the comic pages this information is sourced from.)

In Amazing Spider-Man #28, Peter [graduated from Midtown High School](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RAkP.jpg) with a science scholarship to Empire State University.

In various 1960s issues such as [Amazing Spider-Man #31](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL7e3.jpg), [#45](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBKer.jpg) and [#47](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Aji.jpg), it was stated or otherwise indicated that Peter was a science major at ESU.

According to [a caption in Marvel Team-Up #27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR9yJ.jpg), Peter was specifically a physics major during his undergraduate studies, and [a caption in Marvel Team-Up #28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unU5x.jpg) said he was pursuing a bachelor's degree in physics.

In Amazing Spider-Man #243, he received [a letter from Empire State University](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OK3x.jpg) informing him that he'd been approved for second-year studies in the graduate program of the department of bio-physics, although he dropped out due to money troubles.

Peter demonstrated [computer hacking skills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxm6F.jpg) in Civil War: Front Line #9.

He also developed [Webware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cp6a.jpg), a mobile Internet device with [nanotech-based, self-reconfiguring software and hardware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrs4v.jpg), while running Parker Industries in Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 4.

And he's dabbled in electronics since his earliest appearances, in issues such as [Amazing Spider-Man #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md2Z0.jpg) and [#11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPO7e.jpg).

He wasn't shown using computers much during his college days, but computers weren't anything like as ubiquitous when those stories were published as they are now.

Answer (score 5):

There is at least some very strong indirect evidence. To make his web shooters he needs some deep knowledge of chemistry. Additionally, I think at the earliest in The Amazing Spider-Man 6 his teacher Curt Connors is introduced. And it is stated clearly that he is a Professor of *biochemistry*. Another piece of indirect evidence that Peter Parker's major is chemistry or biochemistry. Later versions of the character differ from this. But the Peter Parker of the original (Lee / Ditko) run studied chemistry.

Comment: I should clarify here that although Spider-Man consulted Connors on science matters a few times in the '60s and '70s, Connors didn't meet regular Peter Parker until Spectacular Spider-Man #32, in 1979, after Peter had already completed his bachelor's degree. Not only had they not met before that, but Connors wasn't a teacher at either Midtown High or ESU before then either. In the aforementioned issue, he'd only recently joined the ESU faculty on a research grant, and became one of Peter's teachers during his postgraduate studies.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Game Spider-man. Shattered Dimension. He finished BS Physics. In the amazing universe though. Earth 616.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe (Vol. 1 #10)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_1) Peter's major in college was **[Biophysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biophysics).**

[image]

Latterly, the [Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe (Vol. 4 #2)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_4_2) indicates that his Doctoral studies are in **[Biochemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biochemistry)**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From everywhere I've seen, It doesn't mention what his major is. I would assume it was photo journalism based on his career with the Bugle, but he also showed an aptitude for biomechanics, engineering and biology. He might have double majored.

Comment: Even in comic books things aren't so ridiculous that he'd double major in journalism and engineering.

Comment: Why not? I know of people who double majored in music performance and mathematics...

Comment: @JohnO One of my friends doubled in Psychology and Computer Science, still completed in the usual 4 years...

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: music is math.

Comment: Not when you ask an academic advisor.

Answer (score 1):

[SCIENCE!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ScienceHero)

Seriously, though, depending on which iteration of Spidey you pick, I would think something like mechanical engineering or (later) biochemistry.

Comment: I think the [omnidisciplinary scientist](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OmnidisciplinaryScientist) is even a closer hit than the [science hero](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ScienceHero) you linked to ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think his major was science because in the amazing Spider-Man, Peter Parker was the 2nd in class in Science, the 1st one was Gwen Stacy. And when he came to oscorp, dr curt Connors was delighted by his science knowledge. But creating the web shooters has something with engineering

Comment: Welcome! :) Thanks very much for your contribution :) This sounds like fair reasoning, but I'm not sure how much it adds to [MPelletier's existing answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/27167/46027)?

Answer (score -1):

Based off of all these, I'm just gonna assume that Peter studied as a Physics major, with a minor in Biochemistry (which tracks, given that that was Sue Storm's doctorate, and Peter was a longtime ally/fanboy of the F4). Also- even though Otto Octavius was controlling him so he didn't technically earn it- Peter has a Doctorate in Robotic Engineering.

Comment: You might want to add sources for that. That last one for instance rings a bell - that's in the story arc where Otto transfers his consciousness onto Peter or something, right? So that he doesn't die?