# Does Peter Parker have a Chemical Engineering degree?

Tags: marvel, comics, spider-man, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In *Spiderman: Into the Spiderverse* during

> the end credits, when we hear Peter Parker singing the song “[Spidey Bells](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSS8PHJ8ZsQ)”

Peter reveals that he has a degree in Chemical Engineering.

In the Marvel comics, does Peter Parker indeed have a degree in Chemical Engineering?

Comment: Someone seems to have done a thorough research [here](https://www.quora.com/What-type-of-engineer-is-Peter-Parker), and if they are to be trusted, it's a no.

Comment: Tempted to close as a dupe of [What was Peter Parker’s college major?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/192050/20774). According to the Official Handbook he has degrees in Biochemistry and Biophysics.

Comment: Note also that this song is intended as a parody. It's not Spider-Man singing it, it's Chris Pine

Comment: @Valorum it's an in-universe song by Peter-1610 (movie version), though. Remember they mentioned the album in the movie?

Comment: @JAB - Well there's your answer. In Peter-1610's universe he has a degree in Chemical Engineering.

Comment: @Valorum the question is about the comics, though, just prefaced by the bit from the movie, so it's not an appropriate answer to the question (as movie 1610 is different from comics 1610).

Comment: In the comics, I don't think the 1610 Peter Parker had time to complete a college degree in anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As indicated in Drifter196's answer, and in the comments above, the 616 version of Spider-Man does not have a degree in Chemical Engineering. As per [What was Peter Parker’s college major?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27163/what-was-peter-parker-s-college-major/192050#192050):

> According to the [Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe (Vol. 1 #10)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_1) Peter's major in college was **[Biophysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biophysics).**
>
> > [image: Peter Parker's education status from Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe (Vol. 1 #10) (transcribed below)]
>
> Currently, Parker has taken an indefinite leave of absence from the graduate program in biophysics at Empire State University, and has taken up full-time freelance photograph, primarily for *The Daily Bugle*,
>
> ... the [Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe (Vol. 4 #2)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_4_2) indicates that his Doctoral studies are in **[Biochemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biochemistry)**
>
> > [image: Peter Parker's education data from Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe (Vol. 4 #2) (transcribed below)]
>
> **EDUCATION:** College educated (science major), doctorate studies in biochemistry (incomplete)

In the [Marvel-1610](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-1610) continuity of the Ultimates universe, where Miles comes from, Peter was still a high-school student.

However, there are definite deviations in the Spider-verse film From Marvel-1610, including a blonde Peter Parker who's married Mary Jane, so we cannot really draw any conclusions from either Marvel-1610 or Marvel-616 comic book history. Given that the film's 1610 universe is so different, I think we have to take its statements at face value.

So, long story short, in all likelihood, in the Spider-verse 1610 universe, Peter Parker does have a chemical engineering degree.

Comment: In addition, blonde Peter Parker is 26, so he's almost certainly not a high school student in that continuity.

Comment: Suddenly it occurs to me that I have more recent handbooks. Watch this space

Comment: Hmm. Volume 5 just says the same...

Comment: @Valorum: Why spend money on writers when you can just copy the text from the last edition? It's worked for textbook writers over the years...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Meh, nothing's happened in two years, why not copy it over?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I broke up a paragraph, and tried to clarify why we should buy into the Chemical Engineering degree; as always, feel free to revert/edit if I mangled things in your opinion.

Answer (score -1):

No it’s not; according to the Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe (Vol. 1 #10) Peter's major in college was Biophysics, and then in (Vol. 4 #2) of the official marvel handbook his Doctoral studies concentrated in Biochemistry, so I guess he was able to transfer most of his credits from his Biophysics major to a Biochemistry major. But he never finished graduate school because life got in the way and all that, it also explained that he was a credit short and he didn’t have a thesis. But not until when Otto Octavius took control of Peter’s mind and was living his life in the Superior Spider-Man arc. At that point when Otto was living as Peter Parker and realized that Parker never finished graduate school, he enrolled himself into University again and within the year gained a Doctorate in Biochemistry.

By the way Spiderman: Into the Spiderverse got a lot of things wrong about Spider-Man, and the spiderverse storyline. It’s pretty much non canon.

But it is an entertaining movie though lol

Comment: Two points - NONE of the Marvel films (Sony's or otherwise) match comic book canon perfectly. And considering that the film deals with alternate dimensions, the points they make could be "canon"/correct, for those dimensions. Also, I believe Peter / Otto's degree is still under review, as Otto/Peter "plagarized" findings by Dr. Otto Octavius, and was initially revoked.

Comment: It's considered appropriate, when quoting [someone else's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/192050/20774) to include some reference crediting them for their effort

Comment: As far as I can tell, they got a lot wrong with 1610 Spider-Man and in how he died. so I’m pretty sure this isn’t canon, and Otto Octavius did receive his doctorate as Peter Parker. One of the doctors that he was learning under; that claimed “Peter” stole Otto Octavius’ work was a colleague of Octavius when they were both classmates which was Dr. Lamaze, the man who claimed “Peter” stole Octavius ideas, but even soon after Lamaze outburst with threatening to expel “Peter” after his presentation. Otto fought the amazon woman Stunner, and took back the Machine she used to build her virtual...

Comment: ...avatar and Otto created his own avatar as himself. Using that virtual avatar Peter (Otto) confronted Lamaze at his place and Fabricated a whole story explaining how Peter Parker was actually his brilliant assistant who took a lot of his own inventions and ideas was actually from Peter Parker. The following day Dr. Lamaze retracted his statement, and Peter (Otto) proceeded to get his doctorate.

Comment: Okay? I never said the quote was mine. I was just answering a question.

Comment: @Drifter196 - Sure, and it's a good answer. Literally the only problem with it is a lack of referencing

Comment: @Valorum - Okay  lol